# VB digital signal processing

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Is there a way to read digital signal through VB program ?

A remote control connects to a pc through a USB. When someone presses a button on the remote, the USB will capture the signal, which the VB program will read. In other words, the VB program should be able to sense the signal recorded by the USB when a remote key is pressed.

Please let me know if there is any API or other mechanism in Visual Basic to achieve this.

Comment: If the remote connects to the PC via USB, then it probably shows up as a human-interface device, like a keyboard or a mouse. Knowing more about the remote you're using would be helpful.

Comment: There is.  Are you using VB6 or .NET?  And, what device?

Comment: The device is a remote control IR3559 which through its infrared emitter excites the photodiode type sharp every time a key  is pressed.The photodiode with amplifier functions type sharp ISU60 is connected to the PC through Usb. VB.Net is preferred . It has to read the signal captured . Functionality is similar to wireless keyboard .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a server as storage to save to presses of the machine.
On Machine with pressed buttons:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles From1.KeyPress
        Dim FS As New IO.FileStream("file", IO.Filemode.Create)
        Dim SW As New IO.StreamWriter(FS)
        SW.Write(e.keyCode)
        SW.Close()
        FS.Close()
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("file", "domain.com/file", "ftpusername", "ftppassword")
    End Sub
End Class
```

On other machine:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Timer1 as New Timer
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As Eventargs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 1
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As Eventargs)
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("domain.com/file", "file", "ftpusername", "ftppassword")
        Dim KeyCode = IO.File.ReadAllText("file");
        'Do Stuff...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps!